# How to generate Aztec Code in React Native mobile application?

Tags: android, ios, react-native, barcode, aztec-barcode

In one of my `react-native` projects, I need to generate a barcode in this format Aztec Code. I didn't find any package which supports `Aztec Code` format and working. Can anyone help me generate `Aztec Code` format barcode in `react-native`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please take a look at Barcode Writer in Pure JavaScript - https://bwip-js.metafloor.com.  (I am the author of the package.)  It supports both Aztec Code and Aztec Runes.  You can read more about the possible options for Aztec Code at the upstream documentation site https://github.com/bwipp/postscriptbarcode/wiki/Aztec-Code.

bwip-js has an ES6 module for both node-js and the browser, so it will import into your project and can be tree-shaken to reduce size.

Comment: https://github.com/metafloor/bwip-js/wiki/Online-Barcode-API => This solution helped. This would be much appreciated if you build native package for `react-native`